# From an fxsave dump, how to determine whether in x87 or MMX mode?

Tags: assembly, x86, context-switch, x87, mmx

With a saved x87 CPU context from `fnsave`, `fxsave`, `xsave` etc., is there a way to know whether the processor was last in x87 or MMX mode?  I'm wondering for purposes of what to show from a crash dump.

I imagine it could be inferred from the tag word, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Good question.  If there's nothing obvious in the docs, I might start by comparing hexdumps of `fxsave` state after `finit` vs. `finit` / `pxor mm0, mm0` or `movq mm0, mm0`.

Comment: The [tag word](https://xem.github.io/minix86/manual/intel-x86-and-64-manual-vol1/o_7281d5ea06a5b67a-198.html) should have 00 if the corresponding FPU register has something useful inside. No idea whether MMX instructions update it. That's probably a tip for an experiment.

Comment: [Some more details](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/acl2/manuals/current/manual/index-seo.php/X86ISA____MMX-REGISTERS-READS-AND-WRITES). MMX instructions also set the tag to valid, so that's unhelpful. "bits 64 through 79 of the corresponding floating-point register are set to all 1s" seems more promising.

Comment: @teapot418 Yeah, you're right.  I guess you could perhaps check if the FP registers hold something that has [all ones in the exponent and sign](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44738755/417501), a state that is otherwise illegal.